# Screen freezes (mouse still movable), goes to black, then goes back to what I was doing

Tags: 12.04, radeon

So I was watching Youtube when the screen suddenly stopped. The sound worked, I moved the mouse around. The sound cut out, the screen went black. This also happens in some of my other thing I do, like playing Dota 2. I'll be loading up my game, when suddenly it goes to black, and then goes back to the desktop, this time with the game NOT open. I checked my temps, k10temp-pci-00c3 gets +0.0C, radeon-pci-0100 gets +29.0C.

My specs:

> AMD Anthlon x4 3.8ghz quad core
>
> 16 GiB RAM
>
> Powercolor PCS+ Radeon R9 270x (GPU)
>
> Seagate 1tb HDD

edit:
Dota 2 problem solved. Reset the advanced settings to defaults and then turned off high quality water for maximum FPS.

The problem doesn't frustrate me, just annoys me.

Comment: This happens when the video driver crashes. It could be from an outdated driver or it could be from overheating. It also seems to be a problem with AMD graphics, since I have the same problem with my Radeon HD 5650.

Comment: Check the `Additional Drivers` app to see if you have the proprietary driver for the card.

Comment: I have the first problem fixed with Dota 2 not loading. Bad airflow and the Render Quality was so low it crashed the game (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

"Everything freezes but mouse moves" is a well-known class of video driver-related errors. Try changing video driver version or proprietary/opensource or whatever. 
In Ubuntu, it may be helpful to install CCSM, and fiddle with compositing parameters there, especially VSync and OpenGL and refresh rate - related. 
Radeon + Linux = bad voodoo, your case is most likely related to video driver.

Comment: I feel like this would be better suited as a comment.